# HOw to do linq to collection query to retrieve specific type

Tags: vb.net, linq, combobox, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I want to bind Combo box with IList(Of LookupItem) so, when i access combobox item then it should be able to cast with LookupItem Object.

Below is code

`cboFilterValues.DataSource = (From i In allDetails Select New LookUpItem With {.ItemText = i.ClassCode, .ItemValue = i.ClassCode}).ToList()`

Now, when i try to cast combobox selected item with LookupItem then it gives exception as its type is mismatch because, item's type is string instead of LookupItem.
Please suggest me what should i change so, I can get selected item as LookupItem.

Comment: I'm not going to put this as an answer since I am not confident enough in my vb.Net skills to be sure this is an answer but start by checking the selected value of the combo box, most likely you are getting a selected value as a property of the item for instance the value of the combobox is Classcode.  My suggested fix is to change the ".ItemValue = i.ClassCode" to ".ItemValue = i" but as I said i don't really know vb.net, but that is the place i would start

Answer (score 0):

Changed to as follow:

`boFilterValues.DataSource = (From i In allDetails Select New LookUpItem With {.ItemText = i.ClassCode, .ItemValue = i.ClassCode})
                    cboFilterValues.DisplayMember = "ItemText"
                    cboFilterValues.ValueMember = "ItemValue"`

I just added above two lines... might be something was wrong before else it would work.

ThankYou.